# How to use JPA annotation if the column is not present now but it will be added later in time

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm using JPA annotations to bind table columns to entities properties. One of my entities have *amount* and *currency* properties. Currently, only the *amount* property is being mapped to database - in a near future, the *currency* property is going to be mapped too.

I want both properties in my entity, even if the *currency* column isn't present in the table yet. For now, it should be null.

Comment: you could use `@jakarta.persistence.Transient` for now

Comment: You can't really do this exactly because JPA needs to know what columns to fetch to build your entities - so if you map it with the column, you are telling JPA it needs to be fetched. There is no JPA option to check if it exists and ignore it if it doesn't. That said, YOU do know it, since you haven't created it. You can map your entities as you hope they will be later on, and override the mappings with an ORM.xml to make these missing columns 'Transient'. You can then modify or remove the orm.xml file when the DB is updated without recompiling or changing the entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't add this as a comment because I don't have enough reputation.

To handle this you could use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) to represent the full response including the amount and currency fields.
You can add them to your DTO right now, and they will be null as long as you don't set them. Later, when you add the columns to the database you can add the corresponding fields to your entity and start setting them in your DTO.

Seems like there is no out-of-the-box functionality to ignore non-existing columns.

I hope it gives you some direction.

Comment: By mapping it, you are telling JPA it must persist that data in the datastore, which it cannot do if the column doesn't exist. There isn't a provider that 'should' ignore these fields if the columns don't exist, as the DB will throw exceptions on CRUD operations including them. DTOs are the way around this, as they can do what ever you want, but the Entity should reflect the current table schema in the database.

Comment: Hey Chris, I just double-checked, and you are absolutely right. I was under the impression that EclipseLink could ignore them, but it seems like that's not the case. I've edited my original message to avoid confusing anyone.